# Is there a way to merge multiple XSLT’s to get output in a single output file?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I currently have a development that is generating three different files of three different status of employee from single XML input. Following is sample XML.

```
 <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Demo_Report">
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Flag>HIRE</wd:Flag>
 <wd:Userid>12345</wd:Userid>
 <wd:FirstName>Jack</wd:FirstName>
 <wd:LastName>Jones</wd:LastName>
 <wd:BusinessTitle>Engineer</wd:businessTitle>
 <wd:Country>US</wd:Country>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Flag>UPDATE</wd:Flag>
 <wd:Userid>890767</wd:Userid>
 <wd:FirstName>Mike</wd:FirstName>
 <wd:LastName>Balder</wd:LastName>
 <wd:BusinessTitle>Jr.Engineer</wd:businessTitle>
 <wd:Country>US</wd:Country>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Flag>TERMINATE</wd:Flag>
 <wd:Userid>543908</wd:Userid>
 <wd:FirstName>Bolton</wd:FirstName>
 <wd:LastName>James</wd:LastName>
 <wd:BusinessTitle>Sr.Engineer</wd:businessTitle>
 <wd:Country>US</wd:Country>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 </wd:Report_Data>
```

I have following three XSLT’s that generates three files of different status of employee as shown below.

**XSLT 1**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
     xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Demo_Report" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
     <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
     <File>
      <xsl:text>user,add,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <xsl:text>"User id","FirstName","LastName","BusinessTitle","Country"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <!--  for each Employee section -->
      <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:if test="wd:Flag ='HIRE' and wd:Position Type !=''">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Userid"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:FirstName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:LastName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:BusinessTitle"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </File>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
     xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Demo_Report" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
     <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
     <File>
      <xsl:text>user,update,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <xsl:text>"User id","FirstName","LastName","BusinessTitle","Country"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <!--  for each Employee section -->
      <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:if test="wd:Flag ='UPDATE' and wd:Position Type !=''">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Userid"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:FirstName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:LastName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:BusinessTitle"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </File>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 3**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
     xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Demo_Report" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>
     <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
     <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
     <File>
      <xsl:text>user,terminate,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <xsl:text>"User id","FirstName","LastName","BusinessTitle","Country"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <!--  for each Employee section -->
      <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:if test="wd:Flag ='TERMINATE' and wd:Position Type !=''">
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Userid"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:FirstName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:LastName"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:BusinessTitle"/>
      <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </File>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output File 1**

user,add,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
12345,Jack,Jones,Engineer,US

**Output File 2**

user,update,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
890767,Mike,Balder,Jr.Engineer,US

**Output File 3**

user,terminate,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
543908,Bolton,James,Sr.Engineer,US

Now I have another requirement that 4th file must be generated with all the consolidated data from all the three files in a single file as following.

user,add,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
12345,Jack,Jones,Engineer,US

user,update,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
890767,Mike,Balder,Jr.Engineer,US

user,terminate,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567
User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country
543908,Bolton,James,Sr.Engineer,US

So is there a way that we can merge three XSLT’s to get output in a single file ?

Comment: Well, XSLT 3 has `fn:transform` so it would allow that, as would XQuery 3.1. XProc can certainly do it as well. And if you are good at any command shell or scripting language you can call an XSLT processor and concatenate results as well.

Comment: Both the provided "XML" document and the stylesheets are severely malformed and generate errors while being parsed. Please, provide good ones!!! Like: `<wd:BusinessTitle>Sr.Engineer</wd:businessTitle>` and `<xsl:if test="wd:Flag ='HIRE' and wd:Position Type !=''">` No need to engage the time of a lot of people, while providing them broken code

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 3 or XQuery 3.1 you can run XSLT from XPath with `fn:transform` so in XQuery 3.1 you could use e.g.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;&#10;';

declare variable $sheet-uris as xs:string* external := ('sheet1.xsl', 'sheet2.xsl', 'sheet3.xsl');

declare variable $sheets as document-node()* external :=  $sheet-uris ! doc(.);

let $xml := .
return
  $sheets 
  ! 
  transform(
    map {
        'stylesheet-node' : .,
        'source-node' : $xml,
        'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
    }
  )?output
```

or in XSLT 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:param name="sheet-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'sheet1.xsl', 'sheet2.xsl', 'sheet3.xsl'"/>

  <xsl:param name="$sheets" as="document-node()*" select="$sheet-uris ! doc(.)"/>

  <xsl:output method="text" item-separator="&#10;&#10;"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence
     select="
      $sheets 
      ! 
      transform(
        map {
            'stylesheet-node' : .,
            'source-node' : current(),
            'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
        }
      )?output"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is how you could do it in [XProc 3](https://www.xml.com/articles/2019/11/05/introduction-xproc-30/) (currently supported by [Morgana XProc III](https://sourceforge.net/projects/morganaxproc-iiise/) in beta, documented at https://www.xml-project.com/files/doc/manual.html):

```
<p:declare-step name="concat" xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-inline-prefixes="#all">
    <p:input port="source"/>
    <p:option name="sheet-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'sheet1.xsl', 'sheet2.xsl', 'sheet3.xsl'"/>
    <p:output port="result" sequence="true" serialization="map { 'method' : 'text', 'item-separator' : '&#10;' }"/>
    <p:for-each>
        <p:with-input select="$sheet-uris"/>
        <p:xslt>
            <p:with-input port="source" pipe="source@concat"/>
            <p:with-input port="stylesheet" href="{.}"/>
        </p:xslt>
    </p:for-each>
</p:declare-step>
```

It uses the built-in `p:for-each` step of XProc https://spec.xproc.org/master/head/xproc/#p.for-each together with the `p:xslt` step https://spec.xproc.org/master/head/steps/#c.xslt to run the input source against the sequence of stylesheets provided as the `sheet-uris` option.

Comment: Martin, thanks..this looks little tricky but let me try this.

Comment: @James, did any of the suggestions work out for you?

Comment: No martin, looks like i am close with below one but since it doesn't have ETV/XTT steps..it's not working out.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Demo_Report">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="header2" select="'User id,FirstName,LastName,BusinessTitle,Country&#xA;'"/>

<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <!--  ADD -->
    <xsl:text>user,add,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header2"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Flag='HIRE']"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <!--  UPDATE -->
    <xsl:text>user,update,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header2"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Flag='UPDATE']"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <!--  TERMINATE -->
    <xsl:text>user,terminate,abc@y.com,admin,ghy567&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header2"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry[wd:Flag='TERMINATE']"/>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Userid"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:FirstName"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:LastName"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:BusinessTitle"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
    <xsl:text>"&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: michael, thanks but what if data fields are different for each category ? for example in Update data, if i don't want country data values to be populated and in terminate data, if only userid to be populated?

Comment: You could use different templates matching `wd:Report_Entry` - each having its own `mode`.

Comment: michael, i used different templates matching wd:Report_Entry with its own data fields.But  it's returning last template data for all other templates.Ex - For third template matching , if i give only userid to return, first and second templates are also returning only user id's though it has other data fields in template. Any thoughts?

Comment: To avoid this, i have used 'if' conditions wherever needed.

Comment: @James Do you understand *"each having its own `mode`"*? https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#modes

Comment: michael, i changed report entry for each having its own mode,that's fine. But why can't we add ETV/XTT steps for it ?

Comment: I don't know what "ETV/XTT steps" are.

Comment: Element transformation validations and XML to text transformations.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what this is about. I suggest you post a new question with your new requirements.